# Deadbolt 2 playframwork 2.5 getting issue with Annotations?

Tags: java, web-services, playframework

When i am using anotations like Subject Present it giving me the error

**[ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:
1) No implementation for be.objectify.deadbolt.java.cache.HandlerCache was bound.
  while locating be.objectify.deadbolt.java.cache.HandlerCache
    for parameter 0 at be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.SubjectNotPresentAction.(SubjectNotPresentAction.java:45)
  while locating be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.SubjectNotPresentAction
2) No implementation for be.objectify.deadbolt.java.cache.PatternCache was bound.
  while locating be.objectify.deadbolt.java.cache.PatternCache
    for parameter 2 at be.objectify.deadbolt.java.ConstraintLogic.(ConstraintLogic.java:43)
  while locating be.objectify.deadbolt.java.ConstraintLogic
    for parameter 3 at be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.SubjectNotPresentAction.(SubjectNotPresentAction.java:45)
  while locating be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.SubjectNotPresentAction
3) No implementation for be.objectify.deadbolt.java.cache.SubjectCache was bound.
  while locating be.objectify.deadbolt.java.cache.SubjectCache
    for parameter 1 at be.objectify.deadbolt.java.ConstraintLogic.(ConstraintLogic.java:43)
  while locating be.objectify.deadbolt.java.ConstraintLogic
    for parameter 3 at be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.SubjectNotPresentAction.(SubjectNotPresentAction.java:45)
  while locating be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.SubjectNotPresentAction
3 errors]**

I have i already implemented the Subject , Role and Permission and also implemented HandlerCache and DeadboltHandler and DeadboltHook also.
everythings work but when i am using annotation its gives error.

Answer (score 0):

```
play {
  modules {
    enabled += "be.objectify.deadbolt.java.DeadboltModule",
    enabled += "modules.CustomDeadboltHook"
  }
}
```

put this code in your application.conf file. istead of

```
modules {
    enabled += "be.objectify.deadbolt.java.DeadboltModule",
    enabled += "modules.CustomDeadboltHook"
  }
```

it fix your issue.